# I want to schedule a job on unix cron , 9 AM - 5 PM on weekdays and weekend 24 hrs.. Can you please assist me on this

Tags: unix, cron

I want to schedule a job on unix cron , 9 AM - 5 PM on weekdays and weekend 24 hrs.. Can you please assist me on this.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Questions that just copy/paste the title into the body of the post almost never get a good reception here. Neither do questions that ask *Please assist me*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want weekdays job to run:

```
* 9-16/* * * 1-5 <command>
```

`9-17` is military time from 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM and 1 at the front means it will run every minute. `1-5` is Monday to Friday. You can also try this, but I am not sure if it works for all systems:

```
* 9-16/* * * MON-FRI <command>
```

To run weekend jobs:

```
0 0 * * 6 <command>
```

`0 0` for midnight `6` for Saturday

```
0 0 * * 0 <command>
```

`0 0` for midnight `0` for Sunday

You can also try this, but as before it might not work.

```
0 0 * * SUN
0 0 * * SAT
```